# One word for computer Messages, Pictures and Videos

Tags: single-word-requests

I usually use "data" but I think this word doesn't refer to Messages, Pictures and videos.

I'm trying to say "Share Messages, Pictures and Videos between devices, Smoothly."

But the sentence is too long and I don't want to repeat "Messages, Pictures and Videos" too many times.

I'm thinking about using "Data" or "Output" instead, but they may refer to so many things rather than just "Messages, Pictures and Videos".

Comment: Computer ***output**?*

Comment: Yeah, it might be the right word, but saying e.g. "Share Output's between devices, Smoothly" is incomprehensible?

Comment: How about **media**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for marketing material?

> Seamlessly share messages and media

Or even just:

> Share seamlessly

This doesn't seem to have the same pleasant sound to my ears, but works:

> Share smoothly

*Share* holds that sense generally, if you're in the world of apps. The object is understood.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the normal word for this is ***[content](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/content)***...

> substantive information or creative material viewed in contrast to its actual or potential manner of presentation
> • *publishers, record companies, and other content providers*
> <sub>*definition from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/content)*</sub>
>
> [uncountable] (computing) the information or other material contained on a website or other digital media
> • *online content providers*
> • *Record companies have had to transform themselves into digital content providers.*
> <sub>*definition from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/content1)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I suggest **files**.

> I share **files** with my networked devices and with friends.

In the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/file#h47146916175500) the second meaning of **file** has

> 1.2 *Computing* A collection of data, programs, etc. stored in a computer's memory or on a storage device under a single identifying
>   name. ‘you can save the file to your hard disk’

Comment: But files doesn't refer to messages.

Comment: They are files too, but otherwise why would you share messages between your own devices?

Comment: I couldn't find it in many dictionaries https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/file

Comment: Didn't you see their example sentence? *"In 1982, the management ordered the deletion of all computer files on this subject."*

Comment: Yeah, you are right, in the computer everything is a file, and I totally understand that. but many people may not understand "file" means a message.

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia article on [Graphical User Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) (emphasis by me)

> Large widgets, such as windows, usually provide a frame or container for the main presentation **content** such as a web page, email message or drawing.

It would seem that things displayed on a computer screen which are not icons, containers, or pointers are referred to as **content**.

So you would say "*Share content between devices, smoothly*" Or "*Smoothly share content between devices.*"